# Ask Ubuntu Toolbar Buttons - A set of toolbar buttons for Ask Ubuntu that make it easy to insert links to packages, PPAs, etc

Tags: script, askubuntu

> ### Update:
>
> This script was previously called "Insert APT Link" but has now been renamed. As such, you need to uninstall any previous versions before installing the new one.

### Screenshot / Code Snippet

[image]

### About

This UserScript adds some buttons to the editing toolbar that allow the following to easily be inserted:

- Package installation button:

  [image: Software center]
- Package installation text and icon:

  [stackapplet](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/stackapplet) [image: Install stackapplet]

- Manpage link:

  [manpage for the `ping` command [image: Manpage icon]](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/ping)
- Link to PPA archive:

  [ppa:george-edison55/george-edison [image: Launchpad logo]](https://launchpad.net/%7Egeorge-edison55/+archive/george-edison) ([Click here for instructions on using PPAs.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4983/what-are-ppas-and-how-do-i-use-them))
- Link to Launchpad project:

  [stackapplet [image: Launchpad logo]](https://launchpad.net/stackapplet)

This UserScript is fully compatible with inline editing and the toolbar buttons should show up anywhere there is a WMD editor.

#### License

MIT License

#### Download

You can install the script by clicking the link below:
https://files.quickmediasolutions.com/userscripts/au_toolbar.user.js

#### Platform

Tested on Firefox 11 (and reported to work on Chrome too).

### Contact

I can be reached at `admin@quickmediasolutions.com`

### Code

Written in JavaScript using jQuery.

Comment: Can this be made into an addon? Greasemonkey doesn't work with nightlies :/

Comment: @Roland: Really? (Shame on GreaseMonkey!) Actually, I'm afraid I have never written a Firefox addon. Ever. :(

Comment: I guess this is time for me to brush up on javascript and write a jetpack :).

Comment: Guess who got greasemonkey working since the latest update :D...

Comment: @Roland: Hooray! So what Firefox version are we working with now? :)

Comment: Firefox 8 still, 9 is on the way but hasn't landed yet :)

Comment: Can this be updated to insert this new awesome button? http://meta.askubuntu.com/a/395/235

Comment: @JorgeCastro: Sure - that button looks awesome.

Comment: It looks like apps.ubuntu.com is the preferred way to install now, see here: http://meta.askubuntu.com/a/395/235

Comment: This script is awesome! I [took it and misused it](https://gist.github.com/halirutan/d77c2c6b9332b6ee86ec) to support some long wanted functionality on mathematica.SE. Nathan, I left your name as developer, your company URL and the download link for `livequery.js` in there. Would you mind leaving me a comment under our [meta post](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1043/187) whether this is OK or what I should change? Thanks.

Comment: @halirutan: I don't have an account on Mathematica.SE, but you are more than welcome to use my code and link to my hosted version of Livequery. I'm glad you were able to adapt my code so easily :)

Comment: @NathanOsman Yes, it's tested now by several users and works like a charm. I was having a [chat with Tim Stone](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/10214411#10214411) yesterday about how I could have possibly found things like `StackExchange.MarkdownEditor.refreshAllPreviews()` because they are documented *nowhere*. That's why I'm so glad you did the hard work and I only had to use it.

Comment: @halirutan: Right - I spent a long time playing around with the Chrome Inspector before I figured that one out. Eventually I'm thinking of creating a JavaScript library with a bunch of functions for doing common things on Stack Exchange pages - like creating toolbar buttons, inserting text into the editor, and creating popup boxes. Then UserScripts can just include the library.

Comment: @NathanOsman We found an issue: When you are not logged on SE or if you are a new user, than the markdown editor gets an additional toolbar which makes that your additional buttons are placed at the very left and are not visible completely.

Comment: Please [see this screenshot](http://i.stack.imgur.com/JS1ak.png). The most left *Key* button is the last of the three buttons I'm using. The reason  for this shift to the left seems to be the additional *Links Images ...* toolbar which appears for guests or new users.

Comment: @halirutan: That's so weird. I have had similar problems before and thought I had already fixed that one. I'll take another look when I get a chance.

Answer (score 9):

I've made some improvements:

- [bugfix] At some pages, the button would not be added: Tag wiki and pressing "Add another answer"
- [feature] selected text will now immediately be converted to an APT link
- [feature] URLs like `http://packages.ubuntu.com/package` will now be converted to `package` (technically, it takes the part after the last `/`)
- Code cleanup: stripping `http://` made no sense and was possibly a leftover from copying code directly

Download:

- http://www.lekensteyn.nl/files/insert_apt_link.user.js

Changelog:

- 1.0.0.2 (13 June 2011): Release
- 1.0.0.3 (7 July 2011): [bugfix] the editors textareas for posts seems to have a numeric ID part now.
- 1.0.0.4 (7 July 2011): [bugfix] Edit Posts works now properly again
- 1.0.0.5 (18 January 2015): [bugfix] Apply to https://askubuntu.com/ too, fix API usage, jshint fixes, use new artwork and app URL.

Comment: Thanks! Do you mind if I credit you and update the original?

Comment: @GeorgeEdison: No problem, you may remove the download link from my answer after updating, keeping multiple (out-dated) copies is not a good idea. Could you add an link to this page in the userscript for future reference? E.g. `@website http://stackapps.com/q/2405`

Comment: Chrome is giving me errors when I try to use the button when editing answers: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL
edit:13 // Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'selection'`

Comment: I found the issue: I wrongly assumed that the selection method was something from jQuery (it's part of http://cdn.sstatic.net/Js/tageditor.js). I've also found an issue at the tag editing page which is now fixed. The download link has not changed, do not forget to clear your cache.

Comment: Did a quick fix for the old Insert Apt Link userscript.