# Where are stackoverflow buttons/widgets?

Tags: discussion, app-request

I'm building a simple paste app for long error logs ([`errorpaste.appspot.com`](http://errorpaste.appspot.com)). A user can post error logs and descriptions of them.

Now I want to add a Stack Overflow button or any widget so that the user can post and ask that on stackoverflow. Is there an app for this?

Answer (score 1):

You might want to take a look at my [Insert APT Link](https://stackapps.com/questions/2405/insert-apt-link-making-it-easy-to-insert-an-apt-link-into-your-question-answ) UserScript, which demonstrates how to add a button to the toolbar and associate an action with it. It also demonstrates how to interact with the editor itself.